# How to render different class names based on object value

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a list of objects in my component. I need to switch between multiple classes based on value in the object.
If my object has ErrorLevel == 1, then
I want to have set of classes for different elements:

```
class-red
class-container-red
class-message-red
```

Otherwise if ErrorLevel is something else, 
I want to have set of classes for different elements:

```
class-yellow
class-container-yellow
class-message-yellow
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve what I want with Angular or CSS (or SASS) without having separate method for each class?

See the example code below of what I have now.

```
<html>
<body>
<div *ngFor="let object of myObjects">
<h1 [ngClass]="getCssClass(object.ErrorLevel)"></h1>
<p [ngClass]="getCssClass2(object.ErrorLevel)"></p>
<div [ngClass]="getCssClass3(object.ErrorLevel)"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
export interface MyObject {
    Id: number;
    ErrorLevel: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() myObjects: MyObject[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getCssClass(errrorLevel) {
    if(errrorLevel === 1) {
      return "class-red";
    } else {
      return "class-yellow";
    }
  }

  getCssClass2(errorLevel) {
    if(errrorLevel === 1) {
      return "class-container-red";
    } else {
      return "class-container-yellow";
    }
  }

  getCssClass3(errorLevel) {
    if(errrorLevel === 1) {
      return "class-message-red";
    } else {
      return "class-message-yellow";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following syntax on your HTML elements:

```
<div [class.class-red]="errrorLevel === 1" [class.class-yellow]="errrorLevel !== 1"></div>
```

What this syntax does is that it will check if the condition is true, and if so it will add the class mentioned.

You can also use xyz's solution but I always find that using the `[ngClass]` syntax is way harder to read.

I would also like to mention that naming your CSS class `class-***` is redundant, since you know by the `.` qualifier in CSS that it is a class. Just name it `red`, not `class-red`.

---

Now, there is a better overall solution:

Don't put the class on each element, put the class on the parent div:

```
<div [class.red]="object.ErrorLevel === 1" [class.yellow]="object.ErrorLevel !== 1" *ngFor="let object of myObjects">
    <h1>...</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Then leverage that parent in CSS to style the child elements:

```
.red h1 {
    // style for the red h1
}
.red p {
    // style for the red p
}
...
.yellow div {
    // style for the yellow div
}
```

This is the right way to go, for multiple reasons:

1. Easier to maintain, you just need a single class, and you put it on a single element, you don't have to edit the code in 3 places if you want to add a new error level color when the value is 3 for example.
2. Easier to read, quite obviously, it's only in one place and doesn't pollute the HTML as much.
3. Better performances, Angular doesn't listen for change detection on 3 elements but on a single one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 2-3 cases for error colors, i would rather use next:

```
interface IError {
   id: string;
   color: string;
}

var errors: { [id: string]: IError; } = {
   "e1": { id: "1", color: "class-red" },
   "e2": { id: "3", color: "class-yellow" },
   ...
   "en": { id: "n", color: "class-n" }
};
```

And then implement getValueById method.

**EDIT:**
Maybe this will help you to implement something similar. I wrote this in notepad, if have some error, please don't mind. :)

```
interface IErrors<T> {
    add(key: string, value: T): void;
    remove(key: string): void;
    containsKey(key: string): boolean;
    keys(): string[];
    values(): T[];
    errorClass(key: string): T;
}

class Dictionary<T> implements IErrors<T> {

    _keys: string[] = [];
    _values: T[] = [];

    constructor(init?: { key: string; value: T; }[]) {
        if (init) {
          for (var x = 0; x < init.length; x++) {
            this[init[x].key] = init[x].value;
            this._keys.push(init[x].key);
            this._values.push(init[x].value);
          }
        }
    }

    add(key: string, value: T) {
        this[key] = value;
        this._keys.push(key);
        this._values.push(value);
    }

    remove(key: string) {
        var index = this._keys.indexOf(key, 0);
        this._keys.splice(index, 1);
        this._values.splice(index, 1);

        delete this[key];
    }

    keys(): string[] {
        return this._keys;
    }

    values(): T[] {
        return this._values;
    }

    containsKey(key: string) {
        if (typeof this[key] === "undefined") {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    errorClass(key: string): T {
        return this[_keys]._values;
    }
}
```